# Content block in use Exception when Editing Documents in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am trying to load some Content using Ektron and am running into the following Exception:

```
        System.Exception: com: content block in use
              at Ektron.Cms.EkException.ThrowException(Exception ex, EventLogEntryType                 EventType)
              at Ektron.Cms.Content.EkContent.GetContentForEditing(Int64 Id)
              at Ektron.Cms.ContentAPI.GetContentForEditing(Int64 Id)
              at Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Content.GetContentForEditing(Int64 Id)
              at LoadUtilities.LoadXml(String name, Stream fileContent)
```

Any suggestions on this issue is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Content Block in use" means someone has the content checked out and you tried to Get the content for editing.

Comment: Is there a way to find out who has the Content checked out?

Comment: The Last Editor field will be the user that has the content checked out.

Comment: We opened the document in CMS and there is an option to check-in the file. Checking in the document resolved the load issue. Basically, everytime we open a document in CMS for Editing, that document needs to be checked-in before loading the document using a different route.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue maybe in the xml itself. Review the content in the workarea. If the xml is invalid it may cause a problem.

Comment: we checked the XML and it is valid